# How to use debugger in netbeans that imports the w3c Tidy interface in java

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans, jtidy

I have a bug in my code that uses JTidy to clean some htmls. When it finds a malformed html, I have it to just skip it. But sometimes the program stalls on a malformed html so I want to see what's going on in my code. But I can't seem to run the debugger on netbeans. The debugger stopped on this `Debugger stopped on uncompilable source code.` which is the line `import org.w3c.tidy.Tidy;` The way I run the program is in command prompt with: `java -cp jtidy-r938.jar;. HtmlCleanerTest http://yahoo.com` So is there a way to debug this in netbeans or I have to just use println statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking around Netbeans in project settings, under the libraries category, add the JAR file and it will run on netbeans